# Can amp pages be archived by archive.org?

Tags: html, image, amp-html

AMP usages amp-* tags instead standard tags. If go for AMP only website, no different code and URL for AMP and Non-AMP pages.

Can those pages be archived by archive.org?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can. Here's an example: https://web.archive.org/web/20160921134908/https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/ showing an AMP-only website that's been archived by archive.org